# How to get as <strong> tag as title and its child element as its description using Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

For an HTML input below:

```
example = """<strong>First Title</strong><p>Content of first title</p><p>Content of first title</p><strong>Second title</strong><p>Content of second title</p></strong>"""
```

the output should be:

```
{'First Title': '<p>Content of first title</p> <p>Content of first title</p>', 'Second title': '<p>Content of second title</p>'}
```

and it works exactly using below code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'html.parser')

finalOutput = {}
for header in soup.find_all('strong'):
    title = header.get_text().strip()
    nextNode = header
    content = []
    while True:
        previousNode = nextNode.previous_sibling
        nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling       
        
        if not nextNode:
            finalOutput[title] = " ".join(content)
            break        
        elif isinstance(nextNode, NavigableString):
            if nextNode.strip():
                content.append(nextNode.strip())
                pass        
        elif isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
            if nextNode.name == "strong":
                finalOutput[title] = " ".join(content)
                break
            content.append(str(nextNode))

print(finalOutput)
```

**But the problem is HTML code contains `<p><strong></p>` and the python code does not work for below type of example:**

```
example = """<p><strong>First Title</strong></p><p>Content of first title</p><p>Content of first title</p><p><strong>Second title</strong></p><p>Content of second title</p></strong>"""
```

So I want the output like below- Text inside `<strong>` should be the key and value should be the text before next `<strong>` tag.

Expected Output:

```
{'First Title': '<p>Content of first title</p> <p>Content of first title</p>', 'Second title': '<p>Content of second title</p>'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `<p>` nodes with `<strong>` child

```
for header in soup.select('p strong'):
    title = header.get_text().strip()
    nextNode = header.parent
    content = []
    ...
```

and in the inner loop check if the `nextNode` child is `strong`

```
...
elif isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
    if next(nextNode.children).name == "strong":
        finalOutput[title] = " ".join(content)
        break
...
```